# Load JSON file to Backbone collection

Tags: json, backbone.js

Hi I'm looking for proper solution to load JSON to Backbone collection. I saw a lot of post with this problem, but I still don't understand how to do it correctly.
For example, Could You explain me  please why this project doesn't work?
http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/22/backbone-js-tutorial-part-1/

**Edit:**
When I look at the results using Firebug, it  shows me an empty object, collection is empty.
Why?
**EDIT:**
hmmm, still doesn't work :/   Now I don't see anything in firebug and one the page.  :(

```
        $(function() {
            var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Profile,
                url: 'profiles.json'
            });   

            var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "#profiles",
                template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
                render: function(eventName) {
                    _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
                        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
                        $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
                    }, this);

                    return this;
                }
            });

            var profiles = new ProfileList();    
            var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});
            var profiles = new ProfileList(); 
            profiles.fetch();
            profiles.bind('reset', function () {
                console.log(profiles);
                profilesView.render();
            });

        });
```

Comment: "*Could You explain me please why this project doesn't work?*" What part doesn't work?

Comment: When I look at the results using Firebug, it shows me an empty object, collection is empty. Why?

Comment: But which part of the tutorial? What code did you execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fetch call is asynchronous, as I'm sure it's written in the tutorial. So when you're doing the `console.log`, your collection is still empty.
Farther in the tutorial..:

```
var profiles = new ProfileList(); 
profiles.fetch({reset: true});
profiles.bind('reset', function () { console.log(profiles); });
```

This should work.